# Yii2 GridView Column Attribute Value

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have two types of selection (radioList & dropDownList) like below, and how i can view the value of STRING not the value of INT? what i should fill in value?

and my result of it is Undefined variable: model

Thank You before

```
 Vitamin | Type

 (A | Tablet) 

 (**NOT** 0 | 2)
```

my _form.php

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'vitamin')
 ->radioList(array(0=>'A', 1=>'B', 2=>'C'))
 ->label('Choose Vitamin') 
 ?>


 <?= $form->field($model, 'type')
 ->dropDownList(
 ['1' => 'liquid', '2' => 'Tablet', '3' => 'Pills', ['prompt'=>'Choose Package']
 ); ?>
```

my index.php

```
 GridView::widget([
 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'vitamin', 
            'filter'=>array("0"=>"A","1"=>"B","2"=>"C"),
            'value' => $model->vitamin == 0 ? 'A' : $model->vitamin == 1 ? 'B' : 'C'
       ],
       [
            'attribute' => 'type',
            'filter'=>array("1"=>"Liquid","2"=>"Tablet","3"=>"Pills"),
            'value' => $model->type == 1 ? 'Liquid' : $model->type == 2 ? 'Vitamin' : 'Pills'
       ],
```

Comment: you never selected the previous answer and added a new one, i see you have multiple questions with upvoted answer, and you never bothered to select any of them why would someone reply you if you are not going to regard them with a few points for helping you out.

Comment: i'm apologize if i offend any colleague in the question forum, really i never mean it, i dont know how to select the previous answer, and what i have to do after someone reply me, really so sorry, hope all the colleague will forgive me @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: and Sir @MuhammadOmerAslam i'm very thank you that you remind me what i should behave in this community, and i'm regret for what i've been done to this community and i hope i can learn a lot from all the colleague, thank you so much

Comment: it wasn't about making you feel guilty but to get better replies to your own questions that would help you out in so many ways see [**`here`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and do accordingly

Comment: Thank You @MuhammadOmerAslam, i read it and thank you so much for helping me

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Sir, can you help me about my question above? Thank you so much before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answers

```
[
    'attribute' => 'vitamin', 
    'filter'=>array("0"=>"A","1"=>"B","2"=>"C"),
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return $model->vitamin == 0 ? 'A' : ($model->vitamin == 1 ? 'B' : 'C');
    }
],
[
    'attribute' => 'type',
    'filter'=>array("1"=>"Liquid","2"=>"Tablet","3"=>"Pills"),
    'value' => function ($model) {
         // Nested ternary expressions (deprecated since PHP 7.4)
         return $model->type == 1 ? 'Liquid' : ($model->type == 2 ? 'Vitamin' : 'Pills');
     }
],
```